# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Where is Package Server Utility

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

In WL 6.0 (plugin for eclipse juno) and earlier there was a server utility called 'Package Server' that was in the context menu for a server in the Servers view. This 'Utilities' selection has  disappeared in the Worklight 6.1 version. Is there another way to Package a WL server when using the eclipse plugin? I understand there is a cmd-line "server" call you can make. But, I don't see this command when using the Eclipse plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I have never heard of this option... what exactly is it packaging for you? The only artifacts you need to take from Worklight Studio (commercial edition) to your production server that is running Worklight Server, is the .war, .wlapp and .adapter files - all three available in the bin\ folder of the Worklight project.

Comment: Hi Idan, The 'Package server' utility was a convenience function that would compress a Liberty profile runtime environment. It would package the server and all the applications that are embedded in the server. So, it was a nice development utility for taking a snapshot of a running Liberty profile server with Worklight and associated adapters. I was able to unzip on a different machine and restart the server with minimal configuration. This utility does still exist for a Liberty dev. environment, but no longer exists if you create that environ. with the Worklight 6.1 plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All, thanks for the responses. I found a cmd-line workaround for this, for now.

1. cd to `EclipseJuno`\plugins\com.worklight.studio.plugin.<61 build>\liberty\wlp\bin
2. set **WLP_USER_DIR**= "`Eclipse Workspace`\WorklightServerConfig"
3. Then, run: "server package worklight --include=all --archive=

Key:

`EclipseJuno`: Directory where Eclipse Juno is installed

`Eclipse Workspace`: Eclipse workspace that contains a default worklight server instance

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project 
Run As --> Build Settings and Deploy Target

There should be a option called "build the application to work with a different Worklight Server"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback. The 'Build Settings and Deploy Target' will allow the application to run against a different adapter, but what I'm looking for is the ability to zip up an entire WAS Liberty instance (containing Worklight and associated adapters), drop it someplace else, and start running again.